# Weblogic 10.3.6 SSL with Crt files

Tags: ssl, weblogic, keystore

I have 3 files;

- AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt
- TrustedSecureCertificateAuthority_3.crt
- www_abcd_com.crt

Weblogic asks me Custom Identity Keystore and Custom Trust Keystore jks files. How can i configure a weblogic 10.3.6 server instance with this keys?

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure two keystores. The first one named `Identity store` is the one that you'll put your own certificate and private key. This store would be used as your server's identity and it will send its certificate to clients from this store.

The second one is `Trust store` which contains certificate of all Root CAs or Intermediate CAs which your server will trusts. Clients who wants to make a two way SSL connection to your sever have to have a certificate issued by one of CAs listed in your `Trust store`.

You can specify the address of these stores on `Keystore` tab of your `Server` configuration page. In order to do this, you have to specify following information for each keystore (first screenshot):

- Address of the keystore on server file system
- Type of keystore (mostly JKS)
- Keystore passprase

[image]

As there could be more that one certificate in a keystore and each one has its own alias and password, you have to specify the alias of the identity certificate in given keystore. In order to do this, go to the `SSL` tab of your `Server` configuration and fill the following fields base on keystore file you've created for your server identity and trust (second screenshot).

- Private key alias (alias you have chosen for your private key in identity keystore)
- Private key passphrase
- Two way client cert behavior (set to `Client Certs Not Requested` for one way SSL and `Client Certs Requested and Enforced` for two way)
- Use Server Certs (select this option if you want to make any two way SSL connection from inside your application, like calling a web service on a server which needs two way SSL)

[image]

These screenshots are from WebLogic 12c, but I think these configurations are same in 10.3.6.

Also I suggest to use a GUI tool like [Portecle](http://portecle.sourceforge.net/) to create or manipulate a keystore.

Comment: Hi moghaddam, i couldnt see your shared screnshoot. I've two crt files as named above. and i dont know which is/are will be identity or keystore. You can say me the steps.

Comment: You mentioned that you have 3 cert file. Isn't there any private key for your server? Which one of three certificates specified at your question belongs to your server? I think the third one should be. So you have to have another file (with pfx or p12 extension) containing your private key which could be used to create your identity store. I can see the pictures in my post. try to edit my post to see the direct links to images, there you can copy them and open them separately

Comment: I bought a ssl from Godady now. i have two crt files gd_bundle-g2.crt and abcd.com.crt. How can i install ssl with this crt files on Weblogic?

Comment: A `cer` file contains only a public key. In order to configure the SSL for your server, your server should have a private key for its own. Do you have any private key for your server (in a p12 or pfx file)?

Comment: No, how can i build it, and what will i do with p12 or pfx file.

Comment: The private key (in p12 or pfx) is mandatory to create an identity store for your SSL configuration. Without it, you can't configure your SSL. Godady issues certificates base on a CSR you gave them. How did you generate that CSR? Can you explain the procedure you did to retrieve the certificate from Godady?

Comment: i've generated csr and key files. but how will i build identity ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38610/discussion-between-moghaddam-and-rahman-usta)